# TaskStackBuilder exits from app when back button is pressed in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications

I having trouble getting TaskStackBuilder to work properly.

When a user clicks on a notification from my program, they are brought to a screen that was previously opened from my app's home screen. I want the Home button and the back button on the screen the user is brought to by the notification to bring the user to my app's home screen.
Instead, pressing the Home button or back key exits my app completely.

I've read the relevant developer docs and thought I had followed them and have done additional research here and elsewhere, but (obviously) I must have missed or misunderstood something. I'd appreciate any guidance anyone might offer.

To help teach myself Android programming, I am working on a simple program that tracks and displays the route of a user's run or walk. The entry point for the program is an Activity that hosts a single ListFragment displaying the user's runs and presenting an options menu that allows creation of a new run.
Clicking on a list item or selecting the options menu item starts a second Activity that hosts a single Fragment displaying the details of the particular run. From that Fragment, the user can start tracking that run. 
When tracking gets started, the app launches a Notification that tracking is on-going. Clicking on the notification brings the user back to the Fragment for the run that's being tracked.

When the user navigates from the home ListFragment to a RunFragment, the Home button and back key work as expected - the user is brought back to the home ListFragment.
However, when the user gets to a RunFragment by clicking on a notification, clicking on the Home button or the back button exits the app entirely.
I've tried to set up a synthetic back stack to solve this problem using TaskStackBuilder, but have met with no success.

Here's the relevant code:

An excerpt from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".RunListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RunActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:parentActivityName=".RunListActivity">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                   android:value=".RunListActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Following are excerpts from RunFragment.java, the class that implements the display of an individual run's details and to which the user is brought when clicking a notification.

First, `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ...
}
```

Next, `onOptionItemSelected()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent runListActivityIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(getActivity());
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(getActivity(), runListActivityIntent)) {

                TaskStackBuilder.create(getActivity())
                        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(runListActivityIntent)
                        .startActivities();
                return true;
            }
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {

                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
                return true;
            }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Finally, the code creating the notification and setting up the TaskStackBuilder, which no doubt is where the problem lies:

```
private void createNotification() {
    Notification.Builder mBuilder =
            new Notification.Builder(getActivity())
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text));

    //Create an explicit Intent for RunActivity with an Extra to
    //select the run that's being monitored
    Intent runActivityIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RunActivity.class);
    runActivityIntent.putExtra(RunActivity.EXTRA_RUN_ID, mRun.getId());
    //The stack builder object should create an artificial back stack for
    //RunActivity so that when navigating back from the RunFragment we're
    // viewing we'll go to the RunListFragment instead of the Home screen
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getActivity());

    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(runActivityIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Thanks to all who've borne with me this far. Any hints as to where I've gone wrong will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am also having problems with this. As far as I can tell, it doesn't work properly across all android api levels. I can't get it to work on my Galaxy S5 with Lollipop.